# Selenium IDE - Selecting an option from Popup Menu when the ID is dynamic

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I would like to select an option from the Popup Menu. I tried all possible combinations.

**Steps:**

1. I click on a button
2. Popup menu opens
3. select an option from the list of options.
    a) Edit
    b) Delete

Every time I try to record this though the ID changes.

Comment: Yes your steps looks fine , what issue you facing?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me. I tried to locate the option using its id. But the id keeps changing for each run. I'm unable to find the id of the option. I tried using xpath and //a commands too. It says element not located.

Comment: Did you try XPATH?

Comment: I also tried these commands
Selectpopup (Popup window name) and click //a[2]/span commands.

Comment: Actually selenium IDE as mostly issue with popup. you can try like waitForPopUp | yourwinId | 30000 selectWindow |yourwinId ... close

Comment: I surely cannot answer your question cause I dropped Selenium IDE as soon as I learned about WebDriver. You should stop wasting your time trying to make the IDE work and pickup a programming language (preferably Python) and work with WebDriver.

Comment: I've worked with the IDE for years and consider it very useful for non-programmers who don't have a year or two to learn enough to be productive.

Comment: @Divya please show your code, the selectors you are using, screenshots form the IDE of your steps, etc. thx.

Comment: Without more info this old question should be closed.  At this point it was just "how to deal with dynamic ids"

Comment: you can try using xpath . In that you can use starts-with , contains, ends-with depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Please see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDBp6hErHlY a small example. I'd took youtube.com to show it. `Pause` command was added only to show that popup menu is opened

Please note:

1. When you use *Selenium IDE* in some cases you can choose one of several options in "target" field
2. Sometimes `tail` could be removed. I'd try to remove `/button` but it should be in displayed case

In general, "it depends" which locator you should select. It could be `/a[1]` link (but if there a lot of links on page - you should define *XPath* carefully - please study tutorials about *XPath*), it could be `/li[1]` elements, it could be `(//button[@type='button'][1])` and other kind of *XPath*.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [Testing the popup with Selenium IDE](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7270/testing-the-popup-with-selenium-ide)

IDE (plain Record and Playback) will work only till an extent. When you reach that point, you will have to either start spending a lot of time adding your own commands between various recorded steps or you will have to step into the world of Selenium Webdriver.  I would suggest the latter.

Comment: fyi, seleniumIDE is not only record and play.  It's a great tool that I've used a lot without record and play.  It even allows constructs such as Page Objects, etc.  The only thing I avoid with the tool is... record and play

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest minimize usage of your's Selenium IDE instead of try to write your own code , i would help you in that process. please provide me your HTML code for popup.

Answer (score 1):

> Every time I try to record this though the ID changes.

On some websites the ID of a button (or an element in general) is changing between different page loads (dynamic ID). This means the test case macro will fail at replay as the button has a new ID after each page refresh.

[Solution:](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/webextensions/selenium-ide/click#changingid) Typically some part of the ID remains constant e. g. post-123456 and post-555555. We can use XPath's `starts-with` or `contains` functions to search just for the stable part of the ID. So the selector will be something like this: //*[contains(@id, 'post-')].